# Recover two dates which are between 2 brackets []

Tags: php, date

I got a string with two dates between  2 brackets and separated by a comma like that:

```
[2016-09-07],[2016-11-16]
```

How do I recover these dates and put them in two variables, `$startDate` and `$endDate`?

Comment: You receive these  in a string? or in an array ?  how you receive it?

Comment: They are stored like that in a database

Comment: You should normalize your database. You could strip the `[]` then explode on the comma.

Comment: It's for storing preferences period chart which can be also "15LastDays", "CurrentMonth", "2016", and "[2016-09-07],[2016-11-16]"

Comment: 1 column start date, 1 column end date. Current month = 1st day of month and last day of month. Year = first day of year, and last day of year. etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you obtain as a string  you  can use explode

```
 $myStartString = "[2016-09-07],[2016-11-16]";
```

if you need you can remove the brackets this way

```
 $remove = ['[',']'];
 $myString = str_replace( $remove, "", myStartString);
```

then

```
 $myArray = explode(',' $myString);

 $startDate = $myArray[0];
 $endDate = $myArray[1];
```

Or  wihthout the brackets:

```
$myString = '2016-09-07,2016-11-16';
$myArray = explode(',', $myString);
$startDate = $myArray[0];
$endDate = $myArray[1];
echo $startDate. ' '.$endDate ;
```

But is better if you have a normalized  database

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Preg_match_all("/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/", $myString, $match);
$start = $match[1][0];
$end = $match[1][1];
```

Answer (score 1):

With the use of `explode()` and `str_replace()` you can get the 2 dates you want.

```
$dum_column = '[2016-09-07],[2016-11-16]';
$t = explode(',', $dum_column);

$startdate = str_replace(array('[',']'), '', $t[0]);
$enddate   = str_replace(array('[',']'), '', $t[1]);
```

or `trim()` would also work

```
$dum_column = '[2016-09-07],[2016-11-16]';
$t = explode(',', $dum_column);

$startdate = trim($t[0], '[]');
$enddate = trim($t[0], '[]');
```

Comment: `trim()` would also be an idea